# C#.Net Download contents of SharePoint Online Folder to network drive

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have the following code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://Website.sharepoint.com/sites/Subsite");
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, GetPasswordFromConsoleInput(Password));

            context.Load(context.Web);
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "Documents/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3";


            query.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                <Query>
                                </Query>
                            </View>";

            ListItemCollection folderItems = list.GetItems(query);
            context.Load(folderItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem li in folderItems)
            {
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = li.File;
                if (file != null)
                {
                    //how to download all files
                }
            }
//How to download one single file in the root "Documents" folder with specific name
```

1) I need it to connect to a SharePoint365 website and download all the files in the specific folder in the subsite library. The files are located in the 3rd folder of the document library. The files should go to a network location `\\server\d$\files`

2) I need it to do the same thing but for only one single file in the root location of the document library with an specific name.

Now it gives me this error: `'The 'query.FolderServerRelativeUrl' argument is invalid.'`
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sample code for your reference.

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lee";

            var login = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            var password = "password";

            var securePassword = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);                
                clientContext.Load(web, wb => wb.ServerRelativeUrl);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("mydoc3");
                clientContext.Load(list);                

                Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/mydoc3/ParentFolder/");
                clientContext.Load(folder);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                     <Query>
                                     </Query>
                                 </View>";
                camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
                ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(listItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach(var item in listItems)
                {
                    var file = item.File;
                    clientContext.Load(file);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    if (file != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```